# Creating a link to the top of the page for each tab of an excel spreadsheet in SAS using proc report

Tags: url, sas

My goal is to create a mulitab spreadsheet as an output from `proc report` and have the user able to navigate within each tab using the links I created. This should include going  to the top of the page.  I am a novice programmer and experiencing 
 issues with `proc report`.  I try using the footnote statement with success. I received an error message saying "can not open `Excel`".

Here is my SAS code:

```
%MACRO rpt_top(COL,TITL,YR) ;;

    DATA TMP4;
        SET COMBO(WHERE=(VARNAME=&COL));
    RUN;

    ODS LISTING CLOSE;
    ODS EXCEL FILE= "&my_excel_file."  STYLE=SASWEB 
        OPTIONS   
        (SHEET_NAME ="Test" 
        SHEET_INTERVAL="NONE" STYLE='SASWEB'
        EMBEDDED_TITLES = 'YES' EMBEDDED_FOOTNOTES = 'YES' BOX='YES' 
        /*TAB_COLOR='GREEN'**/ frozen_headers='6'  autofilter='YES'  Autofit_height='yes' orientation='Landscape' suppress_bylines='YES');
    TITLE1 J=LEFT BOLD "TESTING";
    footnote LINK="#'Test'!A4"  '(CLICK TO RETURN TO TOP)';
    ODS EXCEL OPTIONS 
        (STYLE='SASWEB' SPLIT='/'
        orientation='Landscape' suppress_bylines='YES');

    PROC REPORT DATA=TMP4 NOWD;
        COLUMNS VARNAME 
            DEFINE  VARNAME /DISPLAY FORMAT=$32. 'LINE NUMBER DESCRIPTION';
    RUN;

%MEND;
```

Comment: Are you just missing `ods excel close`??

Comment: ODS TAGSETS.EXCELXP has a TOC option, but unfortunately that's not available in ODS EXCEL. You can make a suggestion to have it added though on the SAS BallotWare.

Comment: With frozen_headers=6 a link to A4 , when clicked, will appear to do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

ODS EXCEL CLOSE will normally automatically open then output file in Excel.

When developing your ODS EXCEL output, you are likely attempting to use the same filename while the prior iteration is still open in Excel.  That is when you will see a log message like

```
ERROR: File is in use, c:\temp\sample.xlsx.
```

The alert might be slightly different is using Enterprise Guide.

While developing, either be sure to close Excel before rerunning code, or use a incremental output filename.

For example

```
 filename xlout "c:\temp\sample.xlsx"; * for production use;
 filename xlout "%sysfunc(pathname(WORK))\sample-%sysfunc(monotonic()).xlsx"; * for development use;
```

With the incremental filenaming it becomes easier to compare and contrast effects of statements on output.